# Expose entity Date fields in an Android SDK for Java 7 and below

Tags: android, date, sdk

We plan to release an Android SDK for various customers. The SDK will expose entities with `Date` alike (or DateTime) fields.
However, there is an issue between Java 7 and Java 8, the latter got new classes and a drastic change in how it deals with Dates.

What would be the best way (or type) for exposing Date fields?

Should we use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library for that and use its types or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use this backport

You can also take a look to [Joda time](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) but it seems deprecated since [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) cames out